# resilience4j Time based circuit breaker behaves as count based

Tags: java, circuit-breaker, resilience4j

I'm trying to test a timebased circuit breaker with this configuration :

```
       failureRateThreshold :  50                 
       slidingWindowSize : 2                  
       slidingWindowType : TIME_BASED         
       minimumNumberOfCalls    : 100
```

I was expecting that it triggers the failure rate calculation when 2 seconds passed as `slidingWindowSize=2`,
but it does it when the number of calls exeeds 100 (`minimumNumberOfCalls`).
Even if 2 seconds passed without reaching the 100 calls it never changes to `OPEN` state (even having all calls failed).

Is this a bug or the expected behaviour ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is the expected behavior as it is explained [here on docs](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/circuitbreaker#create-and-configure-a-circuitbreaker)

> Configures the minimum number of calls which are required (per sliding window period) before the CircuitBreaker can calculate the error rate or slow call rate.
> For example, if minimumNumberOfCalls is 10, then at least 10 calls must be recorded, before the failure rate can be calculated.
> If only 9 calls have been recorded the CircuitBreaker will not transition to open even if all 9 calls have failed.